# Python installation issue, IDLE subprocess didn't make connection

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to install python 3.3.4 for the first time on Win Vista OS and it seems to install successfully but when I try to open the IDlE gui I get the error msg: IDLE subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, have tried turning off the firewall completely and have had no luck getting this to work. Everything I have read from people having similar problems is because they had a file in the wrong place or something similar. I have never used this program before, I haven't even been able to open it once so if there is a bad file then it lies with the installation process.

Someone please help, I am completely new to this and would very much like to learn to program with Python.

Comment: Did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888186/cant-run-python-via-idle-from-explorer-2013-idles-subprocess-didnt-make-c

Comment: yes, tried deleting the tkinter file but this made nothing work, not even the control module and this seems to be a 2.7 problem anyways. Never opened the program and so haven't been able to create any other files as some suggested. Tried to reinstall with the exe path but this didn't work either.

Comment: Is there a backdoor method into IDLE? through the command line maybe? I just need it to work well enough to do the assignments in my textbook and I don't care about inconvenience at this point. Just want it to work, even kind of work would be great. The shell comes up fine except for that error msg. I could use it with that error msg covering up my script I guess... as soon as the error msg closes though the whole program says not responding and closes so this doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: I hate to send you down this road but have you tried to install at root instead of in Program Files?  I feel for you as VISTA is the world's second worst operating system and I suspect it has something to do with an issue with Vista and Python permissions but it could be tough to figure out from a distance