# Python IDLE : Subprocess startup Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-idle

[image: Why are those two pythonw.exe there ? is it normal ?]

I have already tried things like installing and uninstalling multiple times. All other posts say things like delete some files(that you may have created?) named "strings.py" or "tkinter.py"
from the directory of IDLE installation. But, couldn't find them neither ever created. Anyway though , i had tried learning Python some months back i had drop the idea  due lack of time and now when i got back to it this happened , i had at that time installed two versions of Python IDLE namely one was some 2.5 and other 3.2.1  , when i tried to run both of them today i got this error and then i deleted them installed many other versions re-installed and nothing helped.I have tried moving installed files to different Drives altogether, installed-uninstalled multiple times.The weird thing is back in those days (approx 6-7 months back out of which i don't remember much) IDLE used to work fine , but this just happened today.
Also,  i added it to  Avast's Exclusions list ? 
Please help !
P.S : in one of the post someone did this and i did the same and i coukld't figure out what had happened.[image: I tried this too , never understood whats happening.]
 I saw some more posts and tried to start Python Shell (current ver. 2.5.4) by opening a random file  "Edit in IDLE" though no error appeared at that instance but , after  again i tried to pen IDLE GUI from start menu it blew up  ! and errors dropped[image: No errors dropped when i opened a random file for Edit in IDLE]

Comment: have you checked the firewall allows the local connections as the error message says? You could run IDLE without the subprocess: `py -m idlelib -n`

Comment: related: [Can't run Python via IDLE from Explorer [2013\] - IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15888186/4279)

Comment: how to do both ? (lol noob here)

Comment: How to configure your firewall depends on your firewall (antivirus programs may also include one) -- the simplest option is to disable it (temporarily) to find out whether the firewall is the culprit. To run the command, just add `-n` argument to your console command that you are already using to start IDLE.

Comment: Holy Avast ! its him , i am almost about to kill avast , avast you had my trust , you broke it. , but hey thanks buddy! You  just helped me Kudos! , but can you give me a away by which i can enable avast and run IDLE too ?

Comment: I don't know how to configure avast not to block local IDLE connections.

Comment: ohk. Anyway  Huge   Thanks again !

Comment: Searching "avast antivirus unblock" with Google returns several promising links, including a youtube video.  Tell it to not block pythonw.exe.  When you have a full solution, please post an answer.  (and add 'avast' to title somehow)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem in 2.7.3. I made a program and saved it in the source file of python with name **code.py**. Because of this I am getting a subprocess error. Then I changed the name of my file and the problem is solved,,,