# IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection.

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, subprocess

My OS is Mac 10.10.5

I have successfully installed Python 2.6.0b2 on this computer.

I have used Python 2.7 before on this computer but now I get this error:

```
IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. 
Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall 
software is blocking the connection.
```

Picture of the error:
[image: (Picture of error) Left is Python 2.7, right is Python 3.6]

Answer (score 1):

for error  >> **IDLE's sub-process** didn't make connection.
( for windows )

> GO control panel > user account > change user account control setting
>   >
>    # change level to down notify

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem few days back. I saved a program i was working with as `threading.py` that clashed with standard python module files.

See if you have a `.py` that is saved same or similar name as python modules and rename / delete it. Especially something latest that you worked on.

Comment: I deleted all the .py files I have and still hasn't worked. I don't know what I need to do now...

Comment: Did u clean from python folders as well as folders you work from?  Also. While IDLE may not work, command line execution should work.

Comment: Also check out this SO posting about more ideas on the problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888186