# Windows 10: IDLE can't establish a subprocess

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I am new to Python and recently installed Python 3.6 on Windows 10. When I try to open IDLE, Python's IDE, I keep getting a message saying that it can not establish a subprocess. I have tried uninstalling and installing several times. I have seen several forums which say that there could be a .py file that is in the directory that is messing up IDLE. This is not my case, as I have not even been able to start using Python and I do not have a firewall either. Can someone tell me how I can get IDLE to work?

Comment: Have you tried to repro this on another machine (A VM would also do it)? I remember to have had also some issues with the same Python and Windows version, and discarded it over a third-party IDE.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're receiving?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error - IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start or personal firewall software is blocking connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567051/python-error-idles-subprocess-didnt-make-connection-either-idle-cant-start)

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997715/idles-subprocess-didnt-make-a-connection-either-idle-cant-start-or-personal/38001829#38001829) I collected together 9 possible reasons for the message, as reported in various SO answers.

If you try to start IDLE from a command line (Command Prompt or PowerShell)

```
> python -m idlelib  # idlelib.idle for 2.x
```

one *might* get a helpful error message.

Answer (score 0):

I work with over 30 Python developers and without fail when this happens they were behind a proxy / vpn. Turn off your proxy / vpn and it will work. Must have had this happen hundreds of times and this solution always worked.