# IDLE's subprocess didn't make a connection. Either IDLE can't start or personal firewall software is blocking connection

Tags: python, python-idle

I have tried uninstalling it and have searched other answers. None of them have worked; IDLE opens, but I can't run anything I write.

Comment: try to restart you computer, worked for me

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but i have already tried that.

Comment: by the way i am running windows 10

Comment: happened to me a lot on windows 7. I don't remember ever checking it online, but in my experience it used to happen when my computer did a lot of things at the same time. It was a slow computer, so I think the cause is some kind of a timeout. Try to close other processes and run it again

Comment: ok thank you, i will try that now

Comment: hi, i closed everything down and tried again and it still didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10
1. Type in "Controlled folder Access"
2. Select "Allow an app through Controlled folder access" Select yes to "UAC"
3. Click on "+ Add an allowed app"
4. Select "recently blocked apps"
5. Find the executable for the C:\Python27
6. Click the + to add it.
7. Select Close
Then try running the Python Shell again. This worked for me 100%

Also, add exception through Windows Firewall Python27 select Private and Public.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before. Based on previous answers, I compiled a list of possible causes and solution on CPython tracker [issue 25514](https://bugs.python.org/issue25514), post of 2016-01-18.

[SO question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888186/cant-run-python-via-idle-from-explorer-2013-idles-subprocess-didnt-make-c) Causes people have found or think they have found.

1. Antivirus/firewall (4 people, linux iptables, Windows firewall, antivisus , so not a myth ;-)
2. Shadow files, as described [in the issue], and in the python directory (about as common; example user file names: tkinter,py, subprocess.py).
3. Registry problem (some people can fix, but most should re-install after complete removal).
4. Zombie pythonw process (kill with Windows Task manager).
5. Permissions (run as admin, though should not be needed with proper install)
6. ?Multiple installed versions clash due to misconfiguration?

[SO question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874757/python-idle-subprocess-error) Add:

7. Running after stopping run with ^C (temporary, I believe Restart Shell will fix)  Call this a timing issue. I have experienced temporary connection failures myself.
8. Modem reboot (rather obsolete answer for most of us).
9. ?example program that reads and writes (test)

Someone somewhere reported that his problem was with network misconfiguration that affected the operation of the socket module that IDLE uses.

Last resort: start IDLE with -n command line option, as described in IDLE doc.

Comment: hi, i have tried and tried and tried but it still doesn't work. the on e thing i haven't tried is starting idle with -n because i don't know how. would you mind telling me how to do it?

Comment: in a console "python -m idlelib -n" (idlelib.idle on 2.7)

Comment: #2 was the cause of problem for me. Deleted 'string.py', 'string.pyc' from "C:\Python27" and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you at the network environment then check on the secure Group (SG), to see if the user is listed under that group.

else as other had been suggested you have to have the (right click on the program the login as Admin right to enable the IDLE to run.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE's subprocess didn't make a connection. Either IDLE can't start or a personal firewall software is blocking the connection.

Having had this problem myself I did an uninstall and created a new directory in the C drive and reinstalled in that folder, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the application.Then reinstall it BUT at the time of reinstallation try  -n at the end of location adress. It worked for me, you can copy the below text and paste it at the location while installing it.

“C:\Program Files\Python32\pythonw.exe” lib\idlelib\idle.py -n